# Display template error for specific keyword search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search, display-template

I am facing a strange issue wherein when I try to search for specific search terms in SharePoint 2013 enterprise search, we get an error as:

> Display Error: The display template had an error. You can correct it
>   by fixing the template or by changing the display template used in
>   either the Web Part properties or Result Types.
>
> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined (CoreRender:
>   ~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display
>   Templates/Search/Item_Results.js)

This is happening only when we search for terms containing names of our Content Types. Other search terms are working well.

Did anyone too faced similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the display template(Item_Result.html) have any error. Possible reasons are **any HTML tags mismatch, Adding symbols(`<!--#_` ) to include Javascript is not closed properly, By retrieving managed property name which is not present**.

Comment: The display template renders the results correctly for all other search terms. Only when I try to search for terms including the content source name, it throws an error.

Comment: Please provide screenshot of what you have searched and provide some details what you have edited in display templates. My imagination is you retrieved the managed property in display template which is not properly get updated. Try by Updating result type property sync in site settings --> Result Types. Sorry, if my imagination is wrong